Can't launch flatpaks from within Gnome Software
Running Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.
Cannot launch flatpak apps through the Gnome Software app, though I can launch them directly by console or the Apps grid just fine. For example I am using Firefox right now even though it won't launch from the Gnome-software app.
I usually get one of two errors, either:

Failed to sync with dbus proxy
ldconfig failed, exit status 256

Some actual examples of the errors shown in Gnome Software:
Chromium - Failed to sync with dbus proxy

Firefox - Failed to sync with dbus proxy

Pinta - ldconfig failed, exit status 256


I see you have made a statement but I do not see a clear question. Please edit the question and have a clear question that might get an answer.

These are the individual steps to be taken (in terminal) when installing Flatpak.
   sudo apt install flatpak
   sudo flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flathub.repo

restart system

   sudo apt install flatpak gnome-software-plugin-flatpak
I would also recommend you then install Flatseal from the Ubuntu Software Center.
Completing those individual steps in the order shown should allow you to use GNOME Software to access Flatpak applications. The restart system step is very necessary.

Thank you. I already have flatpak installed and have been installing their software. I can run the software from the app Grid in ubuntu or terminal, but I can't launch them from within Gnome Software for some reason.
Looking for a fix to this dbus idconfig error.
After installing flatseal, what permission changes should I make or look for, to fix the errors showing?

@Jadeia might be worth exploring with further searches on Flathub Discourse

@Jadeia another Superuser reference to look at.
